# https://fullcalendar.io/ to show only Events Count not the Event related Information

Tags: javascript, jquery

Display only the number of Events per day using JavaScriptFullCalendar  (https://fullcalendar.io/). I have tried the below code.

Display only the number of Events per day using JavaScriptFullCalendar  (https://fullcalendar.io/). I have tried the below code.

```
<div class="row fif-padding">
    <div class="calendar-wrap">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;

        var events = [];
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $("#hdnAppPath").val()+"/MobileHome/CalendarMarkUp",
            success: function (eventdata) {
                $.each(eventdata, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        title: v.Subject,
                        start: moment(v.StartTime),
                        end: moment(v.EndTime),
                        id:v.Id
                    });
                });
                GenerateCalendar(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
        function GenerateCalendar(events) {
            debugger;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                        left:   'prev',
                        center: 'title',
                        right:  'next'
                },
            })
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Actually I want to get the events count per day but I am getting the markup i.e a line expanding for 2 to 3 dates in the calender.

Comment: Then please edit your question to clarify that